# Which is good throw an Exception or return custom object in Spring Boot Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, exception

I create an application in Spring Boot. And I want to know which one is good for following situation.
I have a rest endpoint, and user send an `id` as a *path variable*, then I want to check that `id` is **null** or not, if it is **null**,
***Which choice is good for handling this sitatution?***

###### Choice 1

```
if(id == null || id < 0) {
   throw new BadRequestException("Id cannot be null"); 
}
```

Create a new Exception called `BadRequestException`, then handle it on the General Exception Handler Controller

or

###### Choice 2

Return a custom object contains (status, message, details ...)

Here is the whole method

```
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
public UserResponseVM getIndividualUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    if(id == null || id < 0) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Id cannot be null"); 
    }

    // I got stuck in here therefore method isn't completed

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely option 1, except that you don't have to handle it in the global exception handler if you annotate the exception class with [ResponseStatus](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status) in the following way:

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first solution, and eventually return with status code 400 to indicate input invalid.

That is why 400 status code is for. [HTTP API Errors](https://docs.commercetools.com/api/errors).